# Visual Studio: additional include directories in project settings vs .cpp file settings

Tags: visual-studio

I'm trying to learn pybind11, and I'm using VS2019 to write the code and compile.

I created a project, where I then added a .cpp file and copied some tutorial code.

Now, I go to Project->Properties and set up some parameters, including the "Additional Include Directories" under C/C++->General.
Building then fails with "cannot open include files pybind11.h".

However, I figured out that if I set it in the properties of the cpp-file itself, it compiles.

It seems to me though that this should not be necessary? I.e. the project settigns should apply to all files.

Is there any other setting I need to specify?

Comment: Changing this setting for the wrong Configuration or Platform is a notorious mishap.  Pay attention to the two comboboxes at the top of the dialog.  You want "All Configurations" and "All Platforms".

Comment: I checked, but that did not solve it. (Good point though in any case, I stopped paying attention to that due to the issues I'm having)

Comment: Right-click the project in the Solution Explorer window, the one displayed in **bold text** > Properties > C/C++ > General, "Additional Include Directories" setting.  The one you originally changed should only be modified for #includes that use angle brackets, that is rare.  So it should be `#include "pybind11.h"` in your source code.  Double quotes, not angle brackets.

Comment: It makes no difference whether I use `#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>` or `#include "pybind11/pybind11.h"`. I still have to set the include directory for the file, not the project.

Comment: Are the project and the source file in the same folder? If not, and you have set the "Additional Include Directory" to a *relative* path, then that may be the issue (relative from the project, or from the source).

Comment: The source file is in the "Source Files" subfolder that is automatically created by VS in an empty project. The paths are all set absolute.